# La Quinta Returns nightly rate

Tags: accommodation, hotels, loyalty-programs

I stayed last year in a La Quinta Hotel and I have about 15000 points. I would like to make a reservation using those points but I don't understand if the nightly rate is, for example, (15000 points + 30$) per night or, 15000 points + 30$/night.

If I simulate the booking, the total is 300$ for 10 nights which would confirm the second hypothesis, but it sounds too cheap so I suspect something is wrong. Did I miss something in the program rules?

Comment: Hi Mikel, while I think this question is perfectly on-topic here, I'd suggest you to write and email to the hotel so that you can get an official answer and, in case of trouble, you will have an email sent by them to prove your point.

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  As @Geeo pointed out the question may be on topic but is likely to be closed for other reasons.  It's difficult to follow what you're asking here, soliciting personal experiences or opinions are not constructive, and lastly the question is too localized for the content.  Please review the help link at the top of the page and edit your question accordingly

Comment: @Vince I still don't understand what's being asked.  If it you or OP already confirmed that this is the latter of 2 hypothesis what exactly is the question?

Comment: @KArlson I cannot confirm anything. He tried and the result matches the latter rule, so indeed I don't know why he asked the question, but I guess it could be useful for the next person curious about La Quinta reward program.

Comment: @Vince I don't know if this is a discussion for comments or chat but we both know *the rules/terms/conditions are subject to change without notice*, so today the rules are as worked above I am still not sure what exactly is the question.

Answer (score 2):

99 times out of 100, when a hotel chain offers a Points + Cash booking option, the rate listed is listed in terms of Points *and* cash per night. Neither is a flat rate.

Thus, a 10 night stay would be 150,000 points + 300 dollars at that price. Since most hotel bookings aren't billed until check-in, many chains will allow you to make a reservation like this, even if you don't currently have sufficient points.